# Limit of sequence $f_n(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$
  f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
    n-n^2x, & 0 < x < \dfrac{1}{n}\\[0.3cm]
    0, & x = 0 \text{ or } x > \dfrac{1}{n}
  \end{cases}
$$

What is $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to+\infty} f_n(x)$?

Comment: Care to tell us what you have tried?

Comment: obviously when $f_n = 0$ the limit is 0.

Comment: where $f_n = n-n^2x$ for me the limit is -infinite, but I'm not sure

Comment: For any fixed $x_0$, there exists $N$ (which depends on $x_0$) such that $x_0> \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \geq N$. So for any $n\geq N$, what is $f_n(x_0)$? And therefore what is $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x_0)$?

Answer (score 1):

For $x=0$, $f_n(x)=0$.

For $x>0$, there is always an $N>\dfrac1x$ such that $n>N\implies x>\dfrac1n\implies f_n(x)=0$.

In both cases the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$n \to \infty \implies {1\over n} \to 0$$

This means that if $0 < x < {1\over n}$, we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x\to 0$.

Thus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(0) = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

When $$n\rightarrow \infty$$it follows that $$\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0$$

So the first case is reduced to $x=0$ and the limit is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=0$$